# JQuery: Get Text from another <div> only by class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to access text from an other div only by classes and with JQuery. I'm always struggling with JQuery because I'm not that familiar with it but for the most times i can get it to work somehow.

I tried something like this:

```
$(function() {
$(".quote_button").click(
    function () {
        var text = $(this).parent('.openticket_footer').prev('.openticket_warper').find('.answer_message').text();
        alert(text);
    }
);});
```

And many other ways but i cant figure it out.

The easiest way to show you what i want to do is by this picture:

[Quote function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAfB7.png)

I want to click on the `class="quote_button"`button to access the text in `class="answer_message"`
Here the html code:

```
<div class="openticket_warper">
    <div class="openticket_sidebar float_left">';
        if($result["uID"]==$result_answer["uID"]){
           echo '<p style="font-size: 8pt">Ersteller</p>';
        }
        echo '<p><strong>'. $result_answer["uName"] .' '. $result_answer["Firstname"] .'</strong></p>
        <p style="font-size: 10pt">'. $result_answer["pName"] .'</p>
        <div class="openticket_sidebar_userpicture">
            <img src="images/default-user-icon.png" alt="User Picture">
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="openticket_ticketmesssage">
            <p class="answer_message">'. $result_answer["Message"] .'</p>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="openticket_footer">
        <input class="answerbutton float_right quote_button" type="button" value="Zitieren">
         <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
```

Thank You!

Comment: click on the Quote function to see the picture but i will do an edit to se the HTML, give me a sec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this : Get parent using `parent` method, move to previous `div` and then find `answer_message` to get the text

```js
$(function() {
  $(".quote_button").click(function () {
    var $parent = $(this).parent('.openticket_footer').prev('.openticket_warper');
    var text = $parent.find('.answer_message').text();
    alert(text);   
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="openticket_warper">
    <div class="openticket_sidebar float_left">';
        <p style="font-size: 10pt">Name of the candidate</p>
        <div class="openticket_sidebar_userpicture">
            <img src="images/default-user-icon.png" alt="User Picture">
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="openticket_ticketmesssage">
            <p class="answer_message">Text Message is here</p>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="openticket_footer">
        <input class="answerbutton float_right quote_button" type="button" value="Zitieren">
         <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: @eisbehr, I agree it is not direct parent but parent of parent, hence used `closest` to find it. This way there won't be unnecessary traverse to parent->previous->find

Comment: Probably needs to be `closest('.openticket_ticket')` as this is the nearest common parent

Comment: @eisbehr and Matt, yes you are right. I did not realize it. I have corrected in my answer. Thank you guys.

Comment: @BrushanKawadkar - your edit has gone wrong and lost the call to closest. Should be `var $parent = $(this).closest('.openticket_ticket');`

Comment: @MattWilson, nothing wrong, here `parent` also work as `openticket_ticket` is direct parent to button. Check my code, I have created with running snippet

Comment: Oh ok, your description still mentioned `closest()` so it looks like you've changed approach since your first post.

Comment: @MattWilson, I have changed the description and added code snippet so that you can see it running as expected

Comment: Yes! This one works for me :) Thanks alot to everyone!

Answer (score -2):

```
$(document).on('click', '.quote_button', function(){
   alert($(this).parents('.openticket_warper').find('.answer_message').text());
});
```